# Updating .edmx file results in a ton of errors: 'Object does not exist in System.Data', and others

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio

This solution I just started working on is using Entity Framework, DB first.  I added a column to a table, then in the .edmx file, I right-clicked, did "Update model from DB", then refreshed the table.  It added the new column, but after I save and try to build, I now get 71 errors.  The first several are:

```
The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The solution would build just fine before I did the table refresh.  And if I revert the source code, it all works again. What the heck is going on here?

**EDIT:**

If I add a reference to System.Data.Entity, that takes care of the error I mentioned above.  However, it leaves 33 others:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter'
```

Comment: Did you update across versions? EF 5 introduced a lot of changes from EF 4, not the least of which involved quite a few namespace changes.

Comment: I am brand new on this solution.  But from other threads, yes, I think this must be whats going on.

Comment: From experience, if that's the case, you'll probably find it is easier to delete the edmx and add a new EF 5 (or newer, depending on your tooling) context than trying to fix the existing context. That assumes you don't have a lot of tweaks to the existing context, of course.

Comment: @TiesonT. if I were the only developer, I would. But there are two others.  I think I need to just stick with the current version, EF 4.  I need to figure out how to do that.  Any quick pointers?

Comment: You can manually update the mapping file, and then rerun the T4 templates. Not a lot of fun, that.

Comment: Looks like I am on version 6.1.3

Comment: That is the assembly version, which if you used NuGet to update the solution makes sense, but the T4 templates are what determines how the classes are generated. It sounds like the original templates were for EF4. If you're using Visual Studio 2012 or newer, I don't think those templates are available.

Comment: If you make backup, and delete table, build it and when success, add table back, build again, hopes it works for you.